# Fast modular exponentiation for $60^{53} \text{ mod } 299$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

I'm trying to find the modular exponentiation for $60^{53} \text{ mod } 299$. I know it is $21$, but I would like to to show the answer step by step so that a normal calculator (with no modulo function) would be able to follow the solution steps.

I calculated the binary representation of $53$ = $110101_{2}$ = $2^{0+2+4+5} = 1+4+16+32$.

In the next step, I keep getting wrong results, I just find it very confusing. Can someone show me the correct approach?

Comment: How can you do fast modular exponentiation if you have no modulo function? Are you saying there is no way to calculate say, $3600 \mod 299$, on your calculator?

Comment: @paulinho correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $299 = 13 \cdot 23$, we can use Fermat's theorem for each factor:

$
\bmod 13: 60^{53} \equiv 8^5 \equiv 2^{15} \equiv 2^3 = 8
$

$
\bmod 23: 60^{53} \equiv 14^9 \equiv (-9)^9 \equiv -3^{18} \equiv -27^{6} \equiv -4^6 = -16^{3} \equiv 7^3 \equiv 21
$

Since $21 \equiv 8 \bmod 13$, we get $60^{53} \equiv 21 \bmod 299$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the notation $\text{ mod } x : y \equiv z$ is new to me, what does it mean?

Comment: @Maddow, same as the usual one. I just didn’t want to put the mod at the end